# SQL - How do I use Case When to pivot data and have no duplicate keys in the rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to transpose the In_Type and Out_Type attributes to columns with the DDTM as the data, but the rows cannot have duplicate keys.

My table:

| PT_ID | ARRIVAL_DATE | UNIT | IN_TYPE | IN_DTTM | OUT_TYPE | OUT_DTTM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X125 | 06/25/22 | FT | Transfer In | 6/25/22 18:01 | Transfer Out | 6/25/22 18:04 |
| X125 | 06/25/22 | PD2 | Transfer In | 6/25/22 18:04 | Discharge | 6/25/22 18:59 |
| X588 | 06/27/22 | PD1 | Admit | 6/27/22 09:30 | Transfer Out | 6/27/22 13:00 |
| X588 | 06/27/22 | PD2 | Transfer In | 6/27/22 13:00 | Discharge | 6/27/22 13:30 |

I need my results to look like:

| PT_ID | ARRIVAL_DATE | FT | PD1 | PD2 | ADMIT | TRANS_IN_1 | TRANS_OUT_1 | TRANS_IN_2 | TRANS_OUT_2 | DISCHARGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X125 | 06/25/22 | 1 | NULL | 1 | NULL | 6/25/22 18:01 | 06/25/22 18:04 | 06/25/22 18:04 | Null | 06/25/22 18:59 |
| X588 | 06/27/22 | NULL | 1 | 1 | 6/27/22 09:30 | NULL | 06/27/22 13:00 | 06/27/22 13:00 | NULL | 06/27/22 13:30 |

My SQL Code looks like this but I believe it is incorrect. I need to transpose the Trans_In and Trans_Out into columns that represent the 2 different values.

```
SELECT DBO.[PT_ID], DBO.[ARRIVAL_DATE], 
   max (case when DBO.[UNIT] = 'FT' then '1' end) FT,
   max (case when DBO.[UNIT] = 'PD1' then '1' end) PD1,
   max (case when DBO.[UNIT] = 'PD2' then '1' end) PD2,
   max (case when DBO.[IN_TYPE] = 'Admit' then DBO.[TYPE_DTTM] end) ADMIT,
   min (case when DBO.[IN_TYPE] = 'Transfer In' then DBO.[TYPE_DTTM] end) TRANS_IN_1,
   min (case when DBO.[OUT_TYPE] = 'Transfer Out' then DBO.[TYPE_DTTM] end) TRANS_OUT_1, 
   max (case when DBO.[IN_TYPE] = 'Transfer In' then DBO.[TYPE_DTTM] end) TRAN_IN_2,
   max (case when DBO.[OUT_TYPE] = 'Transfer Out' then DBO.[TYPE_DTTM] end) TRANS_OUT_2,
   max (case when DBO.[OUT_TYPE] = 'Discharge' then DBO.[TYPE_DTTM] end) DISCHARGE, 
 FROM DBO
 WHERE (DBO.[ARRIVAL_DATE] >'06/16/2022'
 GROUP BY DBO.[PT_ID], DBO.[ARRIVAL_DATE]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost done. You just need to add an outter query to aggregate the values of your query using conditions, like this:

```
SELECT
    pt_id,
    arrival_date,
    ft,
    pd1,
    pd2,
    admit,
    CASE WHEN admit IS NULL THEN trans_in1 END AS trans_in1,
    trans_out1,
    trans_in2,
    CASE WHEN discharge IS NULL THEN trans_out2 END AS trans_out2,
    discharge
FROM (
    SELECT 
        pt_id, 
        arrival_date,
        MAX(CASE WHEN unit = 'FT' THEN 1 END) AS ft,
        MAX (CASE WHEN unit = 'PD1' THEN 1 END) AS pd1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN unit = 'PD2' THEN 1 END) AS pd2,
        MIN(in_dttm) AS trans_in1, 
        MAX(in_dttm) AS trans_in2,
        MIN(out_dttm) As trans_out1,
        MAX(out_dttm) AS trans_out2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN in_type = 'Admit' THEN in_dttm END) AS admit,
        MAX(CASE WHEN out_type = 'Discharge' THEN out_dttm END) AS discharge
    FROM dbo
    GROUP BY pt_id, arrival_date
) t
```

Please, check [a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=51ee63f21ece67dc15e05316b916377f).